# Sharing bind volume in Docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

We use open-jdk image to deploy our jars. since we have multiple jars we simply attach them using bind mode and run them. I don't want to build separate images since our deployment will be in air gaped environments and each time I can't rebuild images as only the jars will be changing.

Now we are trying to move towards swarm. Since it is a bind mount, I'm unable to spread the replicas to other nodes.

If I use volumes how can I put these jars into that volume?  One possibility is that I can run a dummy alpine image and mount the volume to host and then I can share it with other containers. But it possible to share that volume between the nodes? and is it an optimum solution? Also if I need to update the jars how can that be done?

I can create NFS drive but I'm trying to figure out a way of implementing without it. Since it is an isolated environment and may contain crucial data I can't use 3rd party plugins to finish the job as well.

So how docker swarm can be implemented in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `docker build`.  Really.

An image is supposed to be a static copy of your application and its runtime, and not the associated data.  The statement "only the jars changed" means "we rebuilt the application".  While you *can* use bind mounts to inject an application into a runtime-only container, I don't feel like it's really a best practice, and that's doubly true in a language where there's already a significant compile-time step.

If you're in an air-gapped environment, you need to figure out how you're going to provide application updates (regardless of the deployment framework).  The best solution, if you can manage it, is to set up a private Docker registry on the isolated network, `docker save` your images (with the tars embedded), then `docker load`, `docker tag`, and `docker push` them into the registry.  Then you can use the registry-tagged image name everywhere and not need to worry about manually pushing the images and/or jar files across.

Otherwise you need to manually distribute the image tar and `docker load` it, or manually push your updated jars on to each of the target systems.  An automation system like [Ansible](https://ansible.com/) works well for this; I'm partial to Ansible because it doesn't require a central server.

Comment: we are already using private registry for those kind. but how to maintain persistance across swarm nodes? should i create a data volume and will that be shared across nodes? if that's the case i've to schedule a backup right?